# php Imagick exportImagePixels use a lot of memory

Tags: php, memory, pixel, imagick

I have following task: I have a big image 3000x2000 also image use all 4 channels so this is RGBA and I need to process each pixels in some way.

My first approach was using standard way like:

```
$this->image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y)->getColor()
```

but I saw that it is very slow, like 45 seconds. The reason is because in such approach for each pixel will be created a class and it will take some time.

Second approach that I think is export pixels as array, so I try next:

```
$lines = $this->image->exportImagePixels(0, 0, $width, $height, "RGBA", Imagick::PIXEL_CHAR);
```

But I saw that page is crashed without any error. After analyzing I saw that it is use a lot of memory. Before calling exportImagePixels it use around 2 mb of RAM, after using export it use 258 mb of RAM(parameter $width=3000, $heignt = 500). I suppose that it should be around 6 mb for this parameters. For example for exported image with size 300x300 it use 18 mb that is a lot.

For measuring memory I use following function:

```
function printMemoryUsage()  {
        $mem_usage = memory_get_usage(true);
        if ($mem_usage < 1024)
            echo $mem_usage." bytes";
        elseif ($mem_usage < 1048576)
            echo round($mem_usage/1024,2)." kilobytes";
        else
            echo round($mem_usage/1048576,2)." megabytes";
}
```

Do you have any idea why it use such amount of memories, and how I could just get a pixel array from Imagick image?

Comment: For a 3000x500 (times 4 for 8 bit rgba) image I would also say 6 MB is appropriate to hold it in memory. BUT, there's more. Maybe a double buffering and also holding PHP and its libraries in memory. I suggest you use image magick command line commands if you are concerned about memory. It also could improve with latest PHP versions. Which one are you using?

Comment: I use PHP version: 7.4.33
about double/triple buffering ok, but it is still should be less then 20 mb.
when I write about 2 mb, this is with loaded image from png. and image in memory. At that point i was able at least print real width and height

Comment: That you need to ask the question implies you're not going to be able to implement the solution - which isn't going to save much memory.

Comment: As I said, PHP itself takes also memory. Use `$mem_usage = memory_get_usage(false);` for measuring! https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: If I use false instead of true I got following result:
392.23 kilobytes, before it was 2 mb
16.39 megabytes before it was 258 mb.

so it is mean that something else is use this memory, do you have any idea how could i check it?